# Why is this $v > c$ example wrong?

Tags: special-relativity, acceleration, faster-than-light

Take an acceleration equal to g for 1 year. Isn't the speed of light reached?  And exceeded after this time? In the Indian journal Pramana
Soviet's scientists made this argument. They explained we leave the realm of special relativity and it's light speed restriction and  enter the realm of general relativity where acceleration is treated.

Comment: If you ignore relativistic effects of acceleration/forces and energy, sure you can exceed $c$ easily enough.

Comment: Just to be clear, you don’t need general relativity to treat accelerating motion in flat space. GR is needed only for gravitational systems.

Comment: Doesn't Einstein thought experiment with the elevator show that acceleration is equal to gravity?

Comment: Larry, no, acceleration is not *equal* to gravity. Gravity is, according to GR, spacetime curvature. Acceleration doesn't require curved spacetime. But this isn't at the root of your question.

Answer (score 2):

> Take an acceleration equal to g for 1 year. Isn't the speed of light
>   reached?

Note that for the [1-D acceleration case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration#Acceleration_in_(1+1)D), the [proper acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration) $\alpha$ (the acceleration measured by an ideal accelerometer attached to the object) is related to the coordinate acceleration $a$ as follows:

$$\alpha = \gamma^3a$$

where $\gamma$ is the [Lorentz factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor).

As the speed of the accelerated object approaches $c$ in some inertial coordinate system, the coordinate acceleration must approach zero for any finite proper acceleration. Thus, assuming constant *proper* acceleration equal to $g$, the speed of the object asymptotically approaches $c$.

I feel certain I've answered one or more similar questions like this but I'm having trouble finding them now. When I do, I'll update with links to these answers.